# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, self

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
class Email_Stuff:
    def Get_From_Email(self):
        self.emailaddr = turtle.textinput("Your Email", "What is your email address?")
    def Get_To_Email(self):
        self.recipaddr = turtle.textinput("Client Email", "What is your client's email address?")
    def Get_Email_Username(self):
        self.EmailUser = turtle.textinput("Your Email Username", "What is your email username?")
    def Get_Email_Password(self):
        self.EmailPass = turtle.textinput("Your Email Password", "What is your email Password?")
    def Send_Email(self):
        import smtplib
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.login((self.EmailUser),(self.EmailPass))
        message = "Python Test Email"
        server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. I have the self's where they should be I think

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? And also, getting rid of the getters would be more pythonic.

Comment: sorry my python skills and vocabulary aren't the best. what do you mean by stacktrace?

Comment: What is the error you see from Python?  Also, where does `turtle` come from?

Comment: python is telling me that i am missing one required positional argument: 'self' . The turtle comes from the import turtle command in tkinter

Comment: @user3133761: Could you please add the complete `stacktrace` in your question?

Comment: Why are you using the turtle graphics module for an email program?

Comment: Please post the code showing how you are trying to use the class you have posted above. Also post the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the problem that your error reports, but in the last line of your code, one of the arguments to `server.sendmail` is `self.message`, but this isn't defined anywhere. You assign `message` right above that line, but not `self.message` which would be a member of the class, rather than a variable in the scope of the function, which is what you have now. I would change that line to: `server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,message)`

Answer (score 0):

**in** `def Send_Email(self):`

```
    message = "Python Test Email"
    server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)
```

you assigned a local variable in the function, `message`, and then used `self.message` in the last line. simple fix to that.

**you can either do this:**

```
    self.message = "Python Test Email" #changed to self.message
    server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)
```

**or this:**

```
    message = "Python Test Email" #changed to self.message
    server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,message) #changed to message
```